# I am displaying the values of a multidimensional array. The values are being displayed but i am getting a notice of Undefined offset

Tags: php

```
if($numrows>0)
{
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($result_page[$i]))         //This is line 68
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_price']."</td>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This is the notice:

**Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in /home/jatin/web/www.exam.com/admin/productlist.php on line 68.**

I am getting this notice because when the loop will be executed for the last time then $i will be incremented and it goes out of the length of the array.

Each time the number of elements in the 2nd dimension changes thus I have to use count function.

The notice occurs when the condition is checked for the last time, So all my elements are displayed but the notice occurs.

Please give an appropriate solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: share your `$result_page[$i]` data

Comment: try this `while(isset($result_page[$i]) && $i<count($result_page[$i])`

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Please read my whole question and answer it. I know why the error occurs but I need the solution.

Comment: can you share which data comes in `$result_page` @YashM.Hanj

Comment: The data comes form a database. So it is always random

Comment: while(isset($result_page[$i]) && $i<count($result_page[$i]) Itried this and it worked for me. Thanks @B.Desai

Comment: can't share the data due to company policy sorry @Bhargav

Comment: ok, my mistake @B.Desai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the @ operator will suppress the notice. If only that is what you are looking for.
Or you can also use this:

```
while(isset($result_page[$i]) && $i<count($result_page[$i])
```

Answer (score 4):

well i found one solution myself also which is not a good option but it also works fine...........use the @ operator like given below ---

`while($i<count(@$result_page[$i]))`

Answers given by B.Desai and thavaamm are better options though.

Comment: It is not solution it will only suppresses error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following function to suppress the warnings.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the array key is set or not then continue loop

```
if($numrows>0)
{
    $i=0;
    while(isset($result_page[$i]) && $i<count($result_page[$i])         //This is line 68
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$result_page[$i]['product_price']."</td>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below one.

```
if($numrows>0)
{
    foreach($result_page as $row)         
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['product_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['product_price']."</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: well i found one solution myself also which is not a good option but it also works fine...........use the @ operator like this `while($i<count(@$result_page[$i]))`